# Customize tinymce to add a custom button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I would like to add a custom button to tinymce interface to upload a image from server.

Scenario:
I have a galley page in my MVC project which allows user to upload images, video, audio and text to the server. These medias are uploaded to the server ie. we have a upload folder on the server where all the files will be uploaded.

I would like to add a button to tinymce which on click will open up a popup with the list of images/video/audio/text(from the server). On select of it the content should be added in to tinymce editor.

The popup would look something like this:
[image]

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Before submit answer why not using an exist file manager like :
http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on the TinyMCE site on how to create a custom toolbar button:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-custom-button/

You can then use the `insertContent` API to inject the HTML you want into the editor after someone picks an image.

Answer (score 0):

Code to add a custom Button:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "your_selector",
plugins: [
    "your_custom_plugin"
],
toolbar1: "undo redo | your_custom_btn",
```

}

```
tinymce.activeEditor.addButton('your_custom_btn', {
    tooltip: 'click to show media',
    icon: 'media',
    onClick : showPopUP()
});
```